# Datatable: date / time sorting plug-in not ordering

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, datatable, datatables, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot app., embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine
I want to order 1 date column of a datatable.

in my POJO:

```
public String getTimeFormatted() {
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(time, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);      
        return dateTime.format(formatter);
    }
```

in the template:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'EEEE, MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a' );

    $('#table').dataTable( {  
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 25,
    }); 
} );
</script>
```

but it does not order properly
[image]

Comment: The trick I do is actually add a span with `hidden` with the unix data time, so DataTable can sort it correctly...

Comment: Datatables sorting is alphabetical if no sort function is specified. The workaround @balexandre uses is ok, but the "correct" way is to define your sorting function based on the date format you are using. https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/#Custom-data-source-sorting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite easy to debug.

I even made a [simple example](https://jsbin.com/xokujuq/1/edit?html,js,output).

You are using a format as `EEEE, MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a` in your code (I assume in spring) but you forgot to translate that into `moment` format... and [from the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), that should be: `dddd, MMMM D,YYYY h:mm,a`

so the code should actually be:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment("dddd, MMMM D,YYYY h:mm,a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use a [`data-order` attribute](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html).  Then I just pass it the timestamp in either `epoch` or `YYYYmmddHHiiss`.

You can see an example here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html