# How to sort DataTable columns by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatable, datatables

I'm using `DataTable` in my Django application. Everything works fine, but sorting by date is wrong. It's sorting as string, not date.

`html:`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.document-table').DataTable({
                "order": [
                    [0, "desc"]
                ],
                "bInfo": false,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: There are various [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[datatables]+date+sort) relating to date sorting in DataTables. Using the `moment.js` library is one popular approach. See [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18).

Comment: Here is one specific example using `moment`: [Datatable: date / time sorting plug-in not ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226347/datatable-date-time-sorting-plug-in-not-ordering)

Comment: Another great approach is to use [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). This allows you to have multiple versions of a value - one for display purposes, one for sorting, one for filtering. So you can display the date as `25-Dec-2020` but behind the scenes you can use `20201225` as the sort value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datatable date sorting dd/mm/yyyy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003222/datatable-date-sorting-dd-mm-yyyy-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem just by removing the line `"order": [[0, "desc"]]`, and ordering dates in django's `views.py` side.